# Check if unordered pair of two columns values is the same and reduce (directional sum) using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df:

| Source | Dest | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 |
| A | B | 7 |
| B | A | 6 |
| A | C | 12 |
| A | C | 5 |
| D | E | 5 |
| E | D | 6 |
| F | G | 1 |

I want to get the 'directional sum' of the values for the (source, dest) tuple. (i.e. combine all the X->Y and Y->X entries and take the weighted sum for the value column with weights equal to +1 and -1 respectively)

df_out:

| Source | Dest | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 11 |
| A | C | 17 |
| D | E | -1 |
| F | G | 1 |

Comment: Why 11 in the first row of the output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You mention groupby in the title, did you try to use it? If it didn't work post your code.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Directional sum of the first 3 columns: 10+7-6 = 11
All instances of A->B and B->A have to be combined to one entry

Comment: @kubatucka Hi, I tried to use min, max columns (of source and dest), to be able to make a comparison, then a weight column (for +1, -1) and a weighted value column (weight*value). Then tried using groupby (summing the weighted value column), but I don't know how to retain the source/dest column order in that. (Plus seemed like a lot of extra columns for the task so thought there might be a better way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `groupby` the sorted values, apply a -1 factor if the direction changed, and sum:

```
group = df[['Source', 'Dest']].apply(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand')

(df.assign(Value=df['Value'].where(group[0].eq(df['Source']), -df['Value']))
   .groupby([group[0], group[1]])
   ['Value'].sum()
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={0: 'Source', 1:'Value'})
)
```

output:

```
  Source  Value  Value
0     A      B      11
1     A      C      17
2     D      E      -1
3     F      G       1
```

Answer (score 1):

We need `np.sort` then can trim the value with the diff

```
df1 = df.copy()
l = ['Source','Dest']
df1[l] = np.sort(df1[l].values,axis=1)
df1.loc[df1[l].ne(df[l]).all(1),'Value'] *= (-1)
df1 = df1.groupby(l)['Value'].sum().reset_index()
df1
Out[83]: 
  Source Dest  Value
0      A    B     11
1      A    C     17
2      D    E     -1
3      F    G      1
```

Comment: Hey thanks! typo on line 4? Shouldn't it be df1[l].ne(df[l])?